# ListPopupWindow closes after typing

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow, mention

I am trying to get a mention type popup working in my app and when the popup window comes up, the user scrolls, and then continues typing the popup window dismisses. Is there any way to keep the popup window open until we call dismiss?

Here's the code I'm working with.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private EditText editText;
    private ListPopupWindow listPopup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        String[] states = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.state_array);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, states);

        listPopup = new ListPopupWindow(this);
        listPopup.setHeight(300);
        listPopup.setAnchorView(editText);
        listPopup.setAdapter(adapter);
        //listPopup.setModal(false);



        listPopup.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position " + String.valueOf(position) + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(!listPopup.isShowing())
                {
                    listPopup.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
                    listPopup.show();
                    listPopup.getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
                    editText.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this? am also facing simillar problem

Comment: @gikarasojokinene I think we ended up using a custom AutoCompleteTextView, not sure why I didn't find to earlier, or why no one else mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, even if I set the `INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED` flag, the `ListPopupWindow` implementation overrode it while resizing the popup.

My solution was to force `inputMethodMode = INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED` everytime I made changes in the list adapter. This solved the flashy popup visibility changes and the popup stayed in place even with adapter updates.

Something like

```
fun updatesAdapterItems(list: List<Items>) {
    inputMethodMode = INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED
    adapter.submitList(list)
}
```